# How to get button id

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a file `Index.aspx` connected to file `seatbooks.js`.
In `Index.aspx` has a button with id `Indexbutton`. `Indexbutton` has `eventonclick='book_ticket()'`. `book_ticket()` method is include on `seatbooks.js`. How to get button id (`Indexbutton`) on `book_ticket()`. Please check my code bellow:

```
 <input type="button" name="submit" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="indexbutton" onclick="book_tickets()" value="Book Seat" />
```

Above is my code on `Index.aspx`. And this is my `book_ticket()` code:

```
function book_tickets() {    
var tickets = jQuery('.seat.selected').length;
//seatId = $('#button').attr('id');   
//var btnId = this.attr('id');
//console.log(seatId);
if(tickets==0)
{
    alert('Please select at least one seat to continue...!');
    return false;
} else if (tickets > 1)
{
    alert('Please select only one seat to continue...!!');
    return false;
}else
{
    x = jQuery('.seat.selected').toArray();
    jQuery('#seat-form-data').html('');
    jQuery('.seat.selected').each
    (
        function () {
            var ydata = jQuery(this).html();
            xdata = ydata.replace("[class]", "");
            jQuery('#seat-form-data').append(xdata);
        }
    );
    jQuery('#seat-form-data').append('<input type="submit" value="submit">');
    jQuery('#seat-form-data input[type="submit"]:first').trigger('click');
    //console.log(xdata);


    // Link to open the dialog
   $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    //event.preventDefault();
}
```

}

I had tried:

```
seatId = $('#button').attr('id');   
var btnId = this.attr('id');
```

And tried to show it on console. But it doesn't work. It say `undefine`. I want to get `indexbutton` (button id) on `book_tickets()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a hard coded ID why do you want to access it via any other way. You can hard code the button Id isn't it?

Anyway, one solution is to pass the dom reference to the function like

```
<input type="button" name="submit" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="indexbutton" onclick="book_tickets(this)" value="Book Seat" />
```

then

```
function book_tickets(el) { 
    var buttonId = el.id;
    ....
}
```

Your code

```
seatId = $('#button').attr('id');
var btnId = this.attr('id');
```

`$('#button').attr('id')` will look for an element with id `button` and if it is found it will return the `id` of that element which is again `button`, same way `this` inside the `book_tickets` method does not refer to the button, it is the window object so `this.attr('id')` will fail.